# Norwegian special characters not showing correctly

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-localization

I have developed a simple application which uses portable object to translate words from english to norsk.

**no.po** (portable object)

```
msgid "Hello world!"
msgstr "Hei Verden!"

msgid "Date Of Birth"
msgstr "Fødselsdato"
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });


    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1)
        .AddViewLocalization();

    services.AddPortableObjectLocalization();

    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(
        opts =>
        {
            var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
            {
        new CultureInfo("en-US"),
        new CultureInfo("en"),
        new CultureInfo("fr-FR"),
        new CultureInfo("fr"),
        new CultureInfo("no"),
        new CultureInfo("nb-NO"),
            };

            opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
            opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
            opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
        });
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseRequestLocalization();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**View**

```
    @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
    @inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
    
    @{
        ViewData["Title"] = "About";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    
    <h2>@ViewData["Title"].</h2>
    <h3>@ViewData["Message"]</h3>
    
    <p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>
    
    <p>@Localizer["Hello world!"]</p>
    <p>@Localizer["Date Of Birth"]</p>

**_Layout.cshtml**

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>@ViewData["Title"] - SuveWebLocale</title>
    
        <environment include="Development">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
            <link rel="stylesheet"
                  href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        </environment>
        <environment exclude="Development">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                  asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                  asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
            <link rel="stylesheet"
                  href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        </environment>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">SuveWebLocale</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
                        <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    
        <partial name="_CookieConsentPartial" />
    
        <div class="container body-content">
            @RenderBody()
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; 2018 - SuveWebLocale</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    
        @*<environment include="Development">
            <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
            <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>
        <environment exclude="Development">
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-tsQFqpEReu7ZLhBV2VZlAu7zcOV+rXbYlF2cqB8txI/8aZajjp4Bqd+V6D5IgvKT">
            </script>
            <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                    asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
                    crossorigin="anonymous"
                    integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa">
            </script>
            <script src="~/js/site.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
        </environment>*@
    
        @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
    </html>
```

Actual output

[image]

As you can see the above image,

F�dselsdato is not properly encoded. I don't know what was the reason behind it. If I missed anything in my code,please advise me to achieve my expectation.

Expected output should be **Fødselsdato**

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you use 'utf-8' as encoding everywhere, then all characters will be shown correct.

Comment: @PoulBak can you post a working answer?

Comment: @PoulBak I have used utf-8 in my _Layout.cshtml page and also I have linked _Layout.cshtml in every page. still it's not showing the characters as expected

Comment: Could you run the test on all browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to resolve the problem. In order to run display international language characters we need to check whether our file is in **UTF-8** format or not. By default it will be in **ANSI** format. We need to convert it from **ANSI** to **UTF-8** using any text editors. I'll show how I fixed it.

Open the portable object (po) file which contains localization texts in **Notepad++** and go to **Encoding** tab and check the format. If it is not in **UTF-8** format convert it to **UTF-8** as shown below.

[image]

Save the file and run the application you would see all the characters show perfectly in browsers.